# Why is it recommended to close hibernate transactions as soon as possible?

Tags: database, hibernate

I was recommended to close hibernate transactions as soon as possible. Can somebody please tell me why this is recommended?

[Please let this question is different from my previous one, as in the previous one I was essentially talking about session connections, but now I am talking about transactions]

Comment: All transactions should generally be closed "as soon as possible". This ensures that any locks, which could be blocking other readers/writers, are released.

Comment: @Since a transaction ensures ACID properties, does a transaction always involve getting a lock on table?

Comment: No it does not. It depends on the isolation level, the operations performed, and the underlying database (and options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any interaction between shared state/data in a multi-threaded environment should be as short as possible to reduce lock hold times during which other threads may not be able to process their work. Closing a transaction can free up such a lock (or multiple locks) and allow the program do other work which it can't do while the transaction is open because the transaction might be touching shared data before closing.

Note that some types of transactions (in an abstract sesnse) are lock-free, but these are probably not what you are dealing with.